# How to call regular JS function with params within jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Is there another way to run a regular JS function with parameters passed than what I use below?
It seems redundant use a on-the-way function to do this.

```
function regularJSfunc(param1,param2) {
  // do stuff
}
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#myId').change(function(){
      regularJSfunc('data1','data2');
    });
}
```

Using a `.bind` event seems much better, however I am not sure how to access the parameters.
**Note**: Example below doesn't work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#myId').bind('change',{'data1','data2'},regularJSfunc);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other than using `bind()` and event properties, you could use [partial function application](http://ejohn.org/blog/partial-functions-in-javascript/):

```
Function.prototype.curry = function() {
 var fn = this, args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
 return function() {
  return fn.apply(this, args.concat(
   Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)));
 };
};
```

(Prototype.js has this extension built in.)

Then your code could look something like

```
$(document).ready($('#myId').change(regularJSfunc.curry('data1','data2'));
```

Comment: I think this was best answer, but didnt use it.
Using map would give extra overhead, which wasnt acceptable since regularJSfunc() gets used by multiple sources.

Answer (score 1):

In your second example, data needs to be a `map`.

```
function myFunc( event )
{
alert( event.data.data1 );
//or alert( event.data['data1'] );
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#myId').bind('change',{'data1':'some data'},myFunc);
}
```

Comment: A character was off. I specified map, so anyone with basic JS knowledge should have picked up on that.

Comment: +1 after your fix. There is no "map" in JS like in Java; though JS's "Object" does the trick. So, anyone with basic Java knowledge should have picked up on it.

Answer (score 0):

No.

[jQuery event handlers](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/) receive a `function` object which they'll invoke with a single argument, the [eventObject](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/). If you want to pass your own arguments, then the alternative you have is passing an intermediate function that will invoke your final function with the arguments you want.

You can achieve that effect by passing an anonymous function, just like you provided yourself in your working example. That's also the *standard* way (with *standard* meaning *what I see everyone doing*) of calling a regular function with custom arguments from a jQuery event binding.

Answer (score -1):

Here is what you were trying to do:

```
$(function(){
    $('#myId').bind('change',{'data':["data1","some data"]},regularJSfunc);
});
```

then you can access the data like this:

```
function regularJSfunc(e){
    var data = e.data.data;
    var data1 = data[0];
    var someData = data[1];
    // do stuff with the data...
}
```

---

and an alternative approach:

```
$(function(){
    $('#myId').bind('change',{"data1":"data1","someData":"some data"}, regularJSfunc);
});
```

then you can access the data like this:

```
function regularJSfunc(e){
    var data1 = e.data.data1;
    var someData = e.data.someData;
    // do stuff with the data...
}
```

Comment: why the -1? Will this answer not work? Sure, its not as clever as the partial function application technique...but it should work...right?